# Can you recommend me 1 or 2 good formal logic books?

Tags: logic, reference-request

I'm interested in philosophical applications, parsing English sentences and practical real-life reasoning situations.  I'm not so much interested in the math/computer science angle.

Comment: You can see Theodore Sider, [Logic for Philosophy](https://books.google.it/books?id=YoV2PgAACAAJ) (2009) as well as Russell Marcus, [What Follows: A Logic and Philosophy Text](http://www.thatmarcusfamily.org/philosophy/Papers/What%20Follows.pdf) (2012).

Comment: Also Peter Smith, [An Introduction to Formal Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=bX91C6GOBkcC&printsec=frontcover) (2003) as well as Valentin Goranko, [Logic as a Tool: A Guide to Formal Logical Reasoning](https://books.google.it/books?id=R687CwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover) (2016).

Comment: What do you mean by "parsing English sentences" ?

Answer (score 1):

> I'm interested ... parsing English sentences

You might really enjoy Harry J Gensler's book, "[Introduction To Logic](http://14.139.206.50:8080/jspui/bitstream/1/2219/1/Gensler,%20Harry%20-%20Introduction%20to%20Logic.pdf)" and in particular his accompanying software, "[LogiCola](http://www.harryhiker.com/lc/)" which is a fun way to practice parsing English sentences and analyzing statements in a logical form.

> I'm not so much interested in the math/computer science angle.

Don't get thrown by the title, but I'd recommend Keith Devlin's "[Introduction to Mathematical Thinking](http://www.mat.ufrgs.br/~portosil/curso-Devlin.pdf)." It was written for use inconjunction with another free resource for learning logic, his MOOC (Massively Open Online Course) through Coursera, "[Introduction to Mathematical Thinking](https://www.coursera.org/learn/mathematical-thinking)" & is a great transitional course from high school mathematics (algebra, arithmetic) to university and college-level mathematics and logic. It covers things like truth tables and quantifiers and is a lot of fun. Devlin - a mathematics professor at Stanford University - is a really good lecturer (you might also enjoy [his lectures on the history of math](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLSa_VV9M4zkums9eDguaORWOlnkdXM-GE)) and the course is very well designed (one of the best online courses I've taken).

> I'm interested in ... practical real-life reasoning situations.

I have not taken this course, but for "practical, real-life reasoning situations", you might enjoy "[A Clear Logical Argument Guaranteed](https://www.udemy.com/a-clear-logical-argument-guaranteed/)" offered by Udemy.com and taught by [Joseph A. Laronge](https://logicguaranteed.com/papers/). It's $50US.

In addition to [Michael Genesereth's Coursera Course](https://www.coursera.org/learn/logic-introduction) course on logic, Stanford also offers an introduction to logic course through EdX: http://online.stanford.edu/course/language-proof-and-logic-self-paced. The course is $55US. They use Jon Barwise & John Etchemendy's "[Language, Proof and Logic](ftp://ftp.fe.up.pt/pub/Deec/fjr/logc/LPL/Extras/LPL%20textbook.pdf)" as a textbook and John Etchemendy is one of the course instructors.

> I'm interested in philosophical applications

In the words of Ludwig Wittgenstein, "Philosophizing is: rejecting false arguments" so you might also want to brush up on logical fallacies:
https://yourlogicalfallacyis.com and
https://bookofbadarguments.com
...and it would be good to start with a basic distinction of [formal and informal fallacies](https://youtu.be/VDGp04CfM4M).

Lastly, a practical example of a philosopher contending with a [Bad Argument](http://www.klemens.sav.sk/fiusav/doc/organon/prilohy/2012/2/9-22.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Try E.J. Lemmon's [Beginning Logic](https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Beginning_Logic.html?id=qkmG04_ecLMC&redir_esc=y) I found it really useful as an introduction to Syllogistic and Propositional logic, and not overly math based.

Answer (score 0):

I can really recommend Priests "An introduction to non- classical logic" for predicate, modal, many value, time and fuzzy logic. Priest uses only tableaux which makes the book very non math friendly.

Answer (score 0):

Richard Arthur's *[An Introduction to Logic](https://broadviewpress.com/product/natural-deduction-2/#tab-description)* is a very easy to read book with a focus on natural language. It has plenty of examples which are formal, and many more from newspapers, TV, etc. It also grows with you, from a beginner who has never seen formal logic to the time when you start to get curious about non-standard logics. A medium size book small enough to be easily carried around, I recommend it highly - and I know it is used in several logic courses at the undergraduate level.